# How to create ".msg" file without using outlook in mfc?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, mapi

I am using outlook 2010. i drag and drop single contact to desktop. contact created on desktop with ".msg" extensions.
this file create in local folder using VC++/MFC

Answer (score 3):

A few options:

1. MSG file format is documented, so you can use straight OLE storage API. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc463912(v=exchg.80).aspx
2. Use Extended MAPI ([OpenIMsgOnIStg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc815715%28v=office.15%29.aspx)).
3. Use [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/home.htm) (I am its author) and its [RDOSession](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm).`CreateMessageFromMsgFile` method. All you have to do is call `CreateMessageFromMsgFile`, populate the properties of the returned [RDOMail](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOMail.htm) object, call `RDOMail.Save`.