# Using redemption without outlook

Tags: mapi, outlook-redemption

I am trying to send a simple email from MSaccess2000 using Redemption. I am on windows10 so cannot load outlook2000 (as I understand it won't work on 64bit)

I have downloaded and installed Microsoft Exchange Server MAPI Client.

Using the code:

```
Dim SafeItem, oItem
Set SafeItem = CreateObject("Redemption.SafeMailItem") 'Create an instance of Redemption.SafeMailItem
Set oItem = Application.CreateItem(0) 'Create a new message
SafeItem.Item = oItem 'set Item property
SafeItem.Recipients.Add "WOODY@WOODEN.CO.UK"
SafeItem.Recipients.ResolveAll
SafeItem.Subject = "Testing Redemption"
SafeItem.Send
```

But it stops on CreateItem and states 'Method or data member not found'

Basically, I have no idea what I am doing, so please keep any answers simple!

Answer (score 1):

`Safe*Item` family of objects in Redemption is designed to use alongside the Outlook Object Model objects, these obejcts cannot be used standalone. Your code above assumes that Application variable above points to an instance of the Outlook.Application object. If you are running in Access VBA, Application intrinsic variable points to the `Access.Application` object, not Outlok.Application.

The RDO family of objects can be used with the standalone version of MAPI, but then there won't be any profiles.

You do need to have Outlook installed. If Access 2000 runs, why wouldn't Outlook 2000 run? All 64 bit flavors of Windows support 32 bit applications.

Comment: Can you give a code example of creating an email with Redemption (without outlook installed) ?

Comment: If Outlook is not installed, you'd need to download and install the standalone version of MAPI - one way or another, Redemption requires the Extended MAPI system to be installed.

Answer (score 0):

Refer these posts:-

[Creating .msg file without COM Interop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41758641/creating-msg-file-without-com-interop)

https://forums.asp.net/t/1798311.aspx?Creating+MSG+file+in+C+without+outlook+installed

[How to create ".msg" file without using outlook in mfc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22299460/how-to-create-msg-file-without-using-outlook-in-mfc)