# Convert Microsoft Graph Message to .msg Format

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api, office365, msg

I am using MS Graph API to get the message but I need to convert it to .msg file and store it on my machine, is there a way to do this?

I need to covert `messageToBeSavedAsMSG` as `.msg` format:

```
            graphClient.users(properties.getUser()).sendMail(
                UserSendMailParameterSet.newBuilder().withMessage(msg).withSaveToSentItems(saveToSentItems).build())
                .buildRequest().post();
        
        //Start saving .msg format
        MessageCollectionPage messages = graphClient.users(properties.getUser()).messages()
                .buildRequest()
                .get();
        
        String msgID = messages.getCurrentPage().get(0).id;
        
        Message messageToBeSavedAsMSG = graphClient.users(properties.getUser()).messages(msgID)
                .buildRequest()
                .get();
```

Answer (score 0):

MS Graph doesn't provide anything for that. The file format is specific to Outlook on Windows only.

The [MSG file format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/exchange_server_protocols/ms-oxmsg/b046868c-9fbf-41ae-9ffb-8de2bd4eec82) is described in full in MSDN. MS Graph (nor EWS) doesn't expose such files in any way. As a possible workaround you can create an MSG file and import EML into it, see [How to create ".msg" file without using outlook in mfc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22299460/how-to-create-msg-file-without-using-outlook-in-mfc) for more information on that.